# How do I find this PDE solutions?

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

For $f:\mathbb{R}^{n}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ and $g:\mathbb{R}^{n}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ could someone help me to find what are the solutions of
\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=1}^{n}\partial_{x_{i}} f + \frac{1}{2}f\left[\frac{\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{n}\partial_{x_{i}}(\|x\|^{2} + g)}{\|x\|^{2} + g}\right] = \frac{n}{\sqrt{\|x\|^{2} + g}}\quad\text{where } g(\textbf{x})\geq \left[\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}\right]^{2} - \|x\|^{2} 
\end{align*}
It seems that $\displaystyle f(\textbf{x}) = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}\partial_{x_{i}}\|x\|^{2}}{2\sqrt{\|x\|^{2} +g}}$ satisfies such equation for each $n$, but I seek for a general solution if it is possible. Any contribution is appreciated.

Comment: Question:  if $f: \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R$, what does $\nabla \cdot f$ mean?  Usually $\nabla \cdot$ is the divergence, but that is defined on vector fields, not scalar functions.  And if $\nabla \cdot$ is the gradient operator, then since the right hand side appears to be a scalar, how does that work?  Could you clarify?

Comment: Dear Robert, thank you very much for the comment. I misused the nabla symbol and replaced it by the partial derivative notation. Hope it is readable now.

Comment: Yes, very much so.  Thanks.  One other question:  if we allow  $g(\textbf{x}) = \left[\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}\right]^{2} - \|x\|^{2} $, singulariies might appear in your equation when $\sum_i x_i = 0$  Is this your intention?

Comment: It might not matter in the light of the newly-posted solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $V=\sum_{i=1}^n\partial_{x^i}$ and $h^2=g+\|x\|^2$. Since $V(h^2)=2h(Vh)$, your equation becomes
$$
Vf+f\frac{Vh}{h}=\frac{n}{h}.
$$
Multiplying by $h$:
$$
V(fh)=n.
$$
Let $a=\sum_{i=1}^nx^i$.  Then $Va=n$, so we obtain:
$$
V(fh-a)=:Vu=0,
$$
where $u:=fh-a$.  To solve this, we use the method of characteristics.  The characteristic system is
$$
\frac{dx^1}{1}=\cdots=\frac{dx^n}{1},
$$
the solutions to which are $x^{i}-x^1=const.$, $i=2,\dots,n$.  Therefore, 
$$
u=U(x^2-x^1,\dots,x^n-x^{1}),
$$
where $U$ is an arbitrary function.  Since $u=fh-a$, we thus arrive at
$$
f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{g+\|x\|^2}}\left(U(x^2-x^1,\dots,x^n-x^{1})+\sum_1^nx^i\right).
$$
Of course, $\sum_1^nx^i=\frac{1}{2}V\|x\|^2$, which agrees with your particular solution.